# How to only pull results when 1 column value is equal for 2 codes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to only receive results where hours in a query match. I've got 2 codes I'm pulling, REG and OT. I only want to receive results where the Reg hours = OT hours and filter out all other instances of REG.

Here's my script, but I'm still pulling in REG hours that don't have corresponding OT hours per employee.

```
select empno, earncode, curhrs, curamt, shfshiftcode, *
from earnings
where earncode in ('REG', 'OT')
and shiftcode like 'N%'
and curhrs = CurHrs
order by 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and table definitions.

Comment: That's a cute try but WHERE works on per row basis, you can't refer to some other row's value. What you want is probably something like: `select * from (select *, count(*) over(partition by empno, earncode, curhrs, curamt, shftshiftcode) as cnt from earnings where earncode in ('REG', 'OT')... ) x where cnt > 1`. If you have multiple REG / OT rows, it won't work, but you can always use MAX/MIN the same way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you want:

```
select e.empno, e.earncode, e.curhrs, e.curamt, e.shiftcode
from earnings e
where e.earncode = 'REG'
and e.shiftcode like 'N%'
and exists(
    select 1 from earnings e1
    where e1.empno = e.empno
    and e1.shiftcode like 'N%'
    and e1.earncode = 'OT' and e1.curhrs = e.curhrs
);
```